# Is php's fopen incompatible with the POSIX open for pipes

Tags: php, posix, pipe, fopen

Why is this so darn confusing. PHP's fopen will not open a file for reading unless there is data in the pipe waiting to be read (according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#41243) comment). The POSIX specification for C's open states that, depending on the state of the O_NONBLOCK flag, when opening a pipe for writing, open will either block the calling process or return an error if no process has the file open for reading. Is this difference reconcilable?

Comment: People elsewhere have suggested for this type of situation that a bash script be invoked to write useless data to the pipe that can be discarded once the open is accomplished. I currently have php opening and closing a C thread to do this read, but since the read is in a loop that will be run every second or so, I would like to try to do this The Right Way and not perform any very expensive operations like thread creation.

Comment: Does [this comment](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php#89642) help? (Essentially, doing a `fopen` with `r+` so you're a writer too...)

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't been able to get this to work. Once I have the file open I use stream_select to loop until I have collected all my input. I would think stream select might never return since there is always a writer with an open handle to the stream handle, however the poster says that his stream select works normally. MY stream select has decided instead to NEVER enter its loop.

`while(($ss = stream_select($r, $w = null, $e = null, 0, 5000)) !=0){read...}`

Comment: Actually I discovered by more thorough testing that the r+ approach doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Php should signal C that it is expecting a connection and then block for input. C should loop while the open call returns -1 and errno == 6, and then fdopen the descriptor. Enjoy.