# Can't read from socket (hangs)

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I am using PHP to connect to a local C++ socket server to keep state between a web app and a couple of daemons.  I can send data to the socket server, but not receive from it; it just blocks on `socket_read()` and hangs indefinitely.  Am I forgetting something dumb (like a NULL character or a different combination of newline characters)?  The PHP is below:

```
socket_connect($sock, $addr, $port); 
socket_write($sock, 'Hello world');
$str = '';
while($resp = socket_read($sock, 1000))
    $str .= $resp;
socket_close($sock);
die("Server said: {$str}");
```

The related part of the socket server is below (note that the `<<` and `>>` operators are overloaded):

```
std::string data;
sock >> data;
sock << data << std::endl;
```

Where `>>` calls `Socket::recv(std::string&)` and `>>` calls `Socket::send(const std::string&)`.

This works fine from (for example) telnet, but PHP doesn't want to play nice.  Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What socket library are you using for C++ or did you create your own (*nix or Windows as well)? Also, what is the error? Is it just blocking forever on sock >> data or is something more happening?An additional note; I haven't used PHP communication with a C++ server in a while, but is your server sending a termination to the socket so it tells PHP to stop reading? Your loop will read continuously in PHP until the server tells it that the socket is done sending information; it's not a real-time update mind you (since it prints the data after it has been totally collected and stored in you var).

Comment: This might just be missing from your code, but did you `socket_create` $sock first?

Comment: Also, I do not see this in your code, but you will need to print $str when your loop completes.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally left out the `socket_create()` from my code - updated above.  I should have clarified earlier, sorry - this is on *NIX.  There isn't any error per se; the server itself works fine (I can telnet and it works as expected) - it's PHP's `socket_read()` that hangs indefinitely.  The socket server is just a temporary one I threw together because I couldn't find a good one to work with (any suggestions would be great).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sockets in PHP, as in most programming languages, are opened in blocking mode by default, unless set otherwise using `socket_set_nonblock`.

This means that unless a timeout/error occurs or data is received, `socket_read` will hang there forever.

Since your termination character seems to be a new line, try that:

```
while($resp = socket_read($sock, 1000)) {
   $str .= $resp;
   if (strpos($str, "\n") !== false) break;
}
socket_close($sock);
die("Server said: $str");
```

Comment: Indeed, I knew they block by default but I completely forgot to either a) close the socket after the response was written or b) break the loop.  Thanks for that.  Using a NULL character doesn't seem to work if I switch it, though (ideally it wouldn't be a newline) - if I try to `strpos($str, "\0")` after `sock << data << "\0"`, it doesn't catch it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Unlike C or C++, PHP does not put null bytes at the end of strings, that's why `strpos` with `\0` yields boolean false when tested. You have to supply another delimiter, use a timeout (see [How to set a timeout on socket read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389645/)), or close the socket from the server's side.

Comment: Fair enough - just realized that through testing on my end as well.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the code could be slightly improved by searching only in $resp: `if (strpos($resp, "\n") !== false) break;`

Answer (score 2):

TCP sockets usually try to combine multiple small send calls into one packet to avoid sending too many packets ([Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)). This may be the cause that you can't receive anything after the send() call. You will have to open the socket with [TCP_NODELAY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_NODELAY) to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this when reading from socket:

```
if(socket_recv ( $socket , $response , 2048 , MSG_PEEK)!==false)
{
   echo "Server said: $response";
}
```

Note: Using **MSG_WAITALL** in place of **MSG_PEEK** might cause socket to hang (from one experience I once had).

Answer (score 0):

I actually just fixed a problem similar to this, except with pipes ([Is php's fopen incompatible with the POSIX open for pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071865/is-phps-fopen-incompatible-with-the-posix-open-for-pipes)). I don't know to what extent the solution would be similar, but maybe worth a look? I agree with RageD that you should stick a cout between the read and write lines just to test and see if the C++ is hanging on the sock >> data line or the sock << data line...

Answer (score 0):

on my opinion this is the optimal solution: https://github.com/graze/telnet-client,

```
$bytesRead = 0;
$out = '';
do { 
    $byte = socket_read($socket, 1);
    $bytesRead++;
    $out .= $byte;
    if (strpos($out, "\r\n") !== false) break;
} while (true);
echo $out;
socket_close($socket);
```