# PHP socket_read will read at most 512 bytes

Tags: php, sockets

```
$input = socket_read($clients[$i]['socket'],2048);
$lent = strlen($input);
echo "\n\n$lent\n";
echo "\nDATA: ".$input."\n";
```

My actual data length to read is >512.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How do you know the length is exactly 2048 bytes? I don't use this method myself, but I do know that if you use variable byte lengths, you first must read the first 4 (i believe) bytes to get the complete packet length.

Comment: the length really of my data is not fixed, and as i check the length of my record it is already 1361 as i used strlen function, but when i used: 
   socket_recv($clients[$i]['socket'], $buff, 2048, MSG_WAITALL); 
i can receive all the data i sent, the problem is my socket_write function, it will prompt an error once i used socket_recv.. 
thank for the reply..@j0k

Comment: Okay, so you know the bytes length and use the socket_read() function to read all bytes. But what is the actual question? Is it going wrong? Are you not getting any output or something else :) ?

Comment: i got an output but not complete, that is really my problem..
the data is cut not complete..
thank you Benz..

Comment: Ah, maybe the total amount of bytes coming trough multiple sockets/connections. What if you try to create a loop with the socket_read function?

Comment: yeah you are right, my design is multiple sockets.. so that is the problem now..i try already but it will hung up after it echo..
i have still other codes to do like socket_write() after i  echo the $input..
my codes is this one:
while ($input = socket_read($clients[$i]['socket'], 2048)) {
echo "\nDATA: ".$input."\n";
}

Comment: o try already your example and it works in reading all my data..
but i got an error when i use socket_write..i try to echo the error and it will prompt "Broken pipe"
my value of $ret is "YES"
socket_write($clients[$i]['socket'], $ret,$len);
$errorcode = socket_last_error();
$errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

Comment: Broken pipe indicates that the connection is closed when sending the bytes. I see you are looping when writing, does the error occur at the first loop or after the first loop?

Comment: good morning @Benz actually this is my codes:
while($input = socket_read($clients[$i]['socket'], 1024)) {  $str1 .= $input;
if (strpos($str1, "\n") !== false)
break;}
....setting the data to write...
socket_write($clients[$i]['socket'], $ret,$len);
$errorcode = socket_last_error();      $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);     echo "\n\n$errormsg";      unset($clients[$i]);
the error is "Broken pipe"..i think i didn't use loop in writing i just use "for loop" in selecting socket..thank you.God bless!

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this thread:

[Can't read from socket (hangs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137661/cant-read-from-socket-hangs)

```
while($resp = socket_read($clients[$i]['socket'], 1000)) {
   $str .= $resp;
   if (strpos($str, "\n") !== false) break;
}
socket_close($sock);
die("Server said: $str");
```

This set of code loops until the response is empty.